# WAMP phpmyadmin 414 error

Tags: mysql, upload, wamp

i am getting the error as follows.
414 Request-URI Too Large

need to change wamp settings from get to post. how can i do this?

i am using my wamp server to execute an import query on a very large data.
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your database is very large it is much better to use the command line processor.

```
Go to wampmanager -> MySQL -> Mysql console
```

This will open a command window and log you into the mysql command processor. You may need to enter the password for 'root' or leave it blank if you have not set one yet.

Then use this command to get the mysql processor to read your backup file and execute all its commands :

```
source /path/to/your/backup/file.sql
```

simple and it will run for as long as is required to complete the restore.